# qmake: could not open config file

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm trying to get Qt running again. I think I screwed a couple of things up by manually deleting the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5` folder.
I think I got most of it reinstalled correctly but not I got the following problem.

When I check the `qmake` version i.e.

```
qmake --version
```

I get the following message.

> qmake: could not open config file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser//default.conf': No such file or directory

I don't understand why there is a second slash in the path. The default.conf file exists in the path without the second slash.

Is there a way to modify the path?

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Suggest : `sudo apt install --reinstall qtchooser qt4-default qt5-default `

Comment: It works for qt4-default. But when I run it with qt5-default I end up with the same problem.

Comment: The setting is Qt4 / "qmake-qt4" by default. Please do: `export QT_SELECT=5 && qmake --version`